# Go closure variable scope

Tags: go, closures

I'm reading 'CreateSpace An Introduction to Programming in Go 2012'

and on page 86 I found this evil magic

```
func makeEvenGenerator() func() uint {
    i := uint(0)

    return func() (ret uint) {
        ret = i
        i += 2
        return
    }
}

// here's how it's called
nextEven := makeEvenGenerator()
fmt.Println(nextEven())
fmt.Println(nextEven())
fmt.Println(nextEven())
```

1) Why is `i` not resetting ?
2) is `nextEven()` returning and `uint` or is `Println` so smart that it can work with everything ?

Comment: 2) Yes, it's returning an `uint`. See the documentation on [named result parameters](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#named-results).

Comment: i was asking because `makeEvenGenerator()` is returning a function pointer (if it's called like that)

Comment: a [play](http://play.golang.org/p/v0YKKdO-G_) of the relevant code.

Comment: *nextEven* is an variable with the type *func() uint*, so nextEven() return an uint.

Comment: @waaadim Functions are values in Go, so `makeEvenGenerator` returns a function value, not a pointer. Therefore the right term would've been 'function' or 'function value' but definitely not function pointer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, I'll assign names to both functions:

```
func makeEvenGenerator() func() uint { // call this "the factory"
    i := uint(0)

    return func() (ret uint) { // call this "the closure"
        ret = i
        i += 2
        return
    }
}
```

The factory returns the closure – functions are first class citizens in Go i.e. they can be right-hand expressions, for example:

```
f := func() { fmt.Println("f was called"); }

f() // prints "f was called"
```

In your code, the closure wraps over the context of the factory, this is called *lexical scoping*. This is why the variable `i` is available inside the closure, not as a copy but as a reference to `i` itself.

The closure uses a *named return value* called `ret`. What this means is that inside the closure you'll have implicitly declared `ret` and at the point of `return`, whatever value `ret` has will be returned.

This line:

```
ret = i
```

will assign the current value of `i` to `ret`. It will not change `i`. However, this line:

```
i += 2
```

will change the value of `i` for the next time the closure is called.

---

[Here](http://play.golang.org/p/zo4mhfqHd2) you'll find a little closure example I wrote together for you. It's not extremely useful but illustrates the scope, purpose and use of closures pretty well in my opinion:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func makeIterator(s []string) func() func() string {
    i := 0
    return func() func() string {
        if i == len(s) {
            return nil
        }
        j := i
        i++
        return func() string {
            return s[j]
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    i := makeIterator([]string{"hello", "world", "this", "is", "dog"})

    for c := i(); c != nil; c = i() {
        fmt.Println(c())
    }

}
```

Comment: it looks like a weird class with one method. the `factory` thing is called only once, like a constructor. and then only the `closure` is getting called. Can ever then need arise to create a closure with arguments ? or is this it's "final state" ?

Comment: If you find this interesting I recommend reading into _functional programming_. The concept of functions as first-class-citizens comes from there.

Answer (score 8):

> 1) Why is i not resetting ?

Closures in Go capture variables *by reference*. That means the inner function holds a reference to the `i` variable in the outer scope, and each call of it accesses this same variable.

> 2) is nextEven() returning and uint or is Println so smart that it can
>   work with everything ?

`fmt.Println()` (along with `fmt.Print()`, `fmt.Fprint()`, etc.) can work most types. It prints its arguments in the "default format". It is the same thing that is printed using `fmt.Printf()` using the `%v` verb.

Answer (score -1):

The variable in closure is free from neither code segment nor context.